# Cocoapods. The spec did not pass validation : 'Cocoa/Cocoa.h' file not found but I have declared the Cocoa library

Tags: cocoa, cocoapods

One of the classes uses `#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>`. So, in my `Podspec`, I include the `framework` `Cocoa`

My `Podspec` is

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name         = "MyCBDLumberJack"
  s.version      = "0.0.1"
  s.summary      = "A customization of CocoaLumberJack"
  s.description  = <<-DESC
                  A customization of CocoaLumberJack
                  DESC
  s.author        = { "Me" => "me@gmail.com" }
  s.homepage      = "https://www.facebook.com/me"
  s.license = { :type => 'MIT',
                :text =>  <<-LICENSE
                  Copyright 2014. Me.
                          LICENSE
              }
  s.source       = { :git => 'https://me@bitbucket.org/me/mycbdlumberjack.git',
                    :tag =>  "#{s.version}" }
  s.source_files  = 'MyCBDLumberJack/My Lumberjack/**/*.{h,m}'
  s.requires_arc = true
  s.framework = 'Cocoa'
  s.prefix_header_contents = '#import "DDLog.h"', 'static const int ddLogLevel = LOG_LEVEL_VERBOSE;'
  s.dependency 'CocoaLumberjack', '~>1.8'
end
```

Why is it so? How should I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because, by default, since you haven't included any [`platform`](http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#platform) attributes when you run `pod spec lint` it is checking the system on both OS X and iOS. Since iOS doesn't have `Cocoa.Framework` this is raising an error.